# Information about the unsubscribed channel stream in actioncable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, actioncable, unsubscribe

Implementing ActionCable Channel in rails.

```
def subscribed

  room = Room.find_by_id(params[:room_id])
  stream_for room
end

def unsubscribed
  room_id = room.try(:id) || params[:room_id] 
end
```

Can we get room_id or room (ActiveRecord obj) information in the unsubscribed method?

Comment: try setting `@room_id=params[:room_id]` in subscribed and you might be able to use @room_id in unsubscribed

Comment: @F.E.A thanks, it is working

Answer (score 0):

Using instance(@) variable in the `subscribed` method, we can get the same object in the `unsubscribed` method

```
def subscribed
  @room = Room.find_by_id(params[:room_id])
  stream_for @room
end

def unsubscribed
  puts "room => #{@room}" # Here we will get the same room object
end
```